# data-hover menu doesn't open for some Chrome users

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have drop-down menus with `data-hover="dropdown"`. I've been getting reports from a few users that the drop-down menus don't appear for them. The most cooperative user says it happens in Chrome 55.0.2883.87m (on Windows 10 14393.576), and doesn't happen on other browsers. I have the exact same Chrome and Windows, and the menus appear fine.

My site: [tipulnagish.co.il](http://tipulnagish.co.il/) - drop-downs open from the main menu.

The site uses Bootstrap v3.2.0, and the menu is basically:

```
<ul id="menu-main" class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="500" data-close-others="false"><span>חיפוש מטפל/ת לפי מקצוע</span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="/listing-category/פסיכולוגי"><span>טיפול פסיכולוגי / פסיכותרפיה</span></a></li>
(etc.)
```

What might be the cause?
I might be able to get TeamViewer access to the user's machine. What should I check on it?

**Update:**

- Also happens on my laptop, which has a touch screen, which appears related.
- [This demo](http://www.jquery-az.com/boots/demo.php?ex=37.0_1) has the same issue. Resolution of [Chromium issue 409383](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409383) suggest it's because the site has special treatment based on `navigator.maxTouchPoints` - I haven't found any such references in my entire site though.

Comment: From personal experience from my previous job, the most common scenario is stuck cache on the browser, apps or extensions interfering with the browser. Try clearing/disabling those, then try if it works in Chrome Canary and only then start looking in the code, since the issue is only reproducible on Chrome 55, Windows 10.
EDIT: btw, same configuration as your customer and everything works fine for me.

Comment: Also, what is the device they are using, Is it a touch device/laptop? Perhaps this could give you some ideas.

Comment: Mine is desktop no-touch comupter, don't know about his. I've compared extension list with mine - nothing out of the ordinary. I don't know whether this repros solely on Chrome55 - that's just the report I have. I'll request to try clearing the cache.

Comment: Followig @yavor's ideas, I found that I have repro on my laptop, which is both Touch and hi-DPI. I'll test on it and report!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `data-hover="dropdown"` trigger the plugin [bootstrap-hover-dropdown](https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown), which includes code that disables hovers on touch-enabled devices:

```
$.fn.dropdownHover = function (options) {
    // don't do anything if touch is supported
    // (plugin causes some issues on mobile)
    if ('ontouchstart' in document) return this; // don't want to affect chaining
```

[The plugin's issue #68](https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/issues/68) discusses this at length, without any good resolution. As a workaround for me, I added `data-toggle="dropdown"` to my markup, so touch users can open the menu with a click/touch. This has some quirks, but works reasonably well with the hover behavior that non-touch users see.

## How I discovered this

Using [Visual Event Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim), I see that the menu bar has bound events `mouseover/mouseout`, which the affected (touch) machines doesn't have. These events are registered `bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js`, which right before that has the above code disabling hover on touch devices.